# Estimating Area Between Shapes

Tags: java, shapes, area

In my class, we are given the task as follows:

> For this assignment you will attempt to make a program for computing the overlapping area of a set of shapes, implementing Monte Carlo integration, as discussed in class.
>   Make AreaEstimator.java, a program that estimates the area of overlap of an arbitrary number of circles and triangles using randomized estimation. The program's arguments will be the number of randomly-generated points to be used in this trial, followed by the coordinates of the points that define the shapes. For example,
>
> java AreaEstimator 1000000 circle 2.0 2.0 1.0 triangle 1.0 1.0 2.5 3.0 2.0 -3.0 circle 2.5 1.0 3.0
>
> would generate one million random points to estimate the overlap of a triangle whose vertices are ( 1.0, 1.0 ), ( 2.5, 3.0 ), ( 2.0, -3.0 ), with two circles whose centers are at ( 2.0, 2.0 ) and ( 2.5, 1.0 ), and whose radii are 1.0 and 3.0, respectively.

Here is my code for the Circle class:

```
public class Circle {
private double xcenter;
private double ycenter;
private double radius;
private double xcmax;
private double xcmin;
private double ycmax;
private double ycmin;


public Circle ( double xcenter, double ycenter, double radius){
    if(radius <= 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    this.xcenter = xcenter;
    this.ycenter = ycenter;
    this.radius = radius;

}
public void maxAndMinCircle (){ //find the minimun and maximum for the plane according to this circle
    xcmax = (this.xcenter + this.radius);
    ycmax = (this.ycenter + this.radius);
    xcmin = (this.xcenter - this.radius);
    ycmin = (this.ycenter - this.radius);

}
public double getXCMax (){
    return xcmax;
}
public double getYCMax () {
    return ycmax;
}
public double getXCMin() {
    return xcmin;
}
public double getYCMin(){
    return ycmin;
}

public boolean outsideCircle(double randX, double randY){ // find if the random point passed thru is in this circle
    double distance = Math.sqrt((randX-this.xcenter)*(randX-this.xcenter) + (randY-this.ycenter) * (randY - this.ycenter));
    return distance >= radius;  
}}
```

The Triangle Class:

```
public class Triangle {
private double cornerx1;
private double cornery1;
private double cornerx2;
private double cornery2;
private double cornerx3;
private double cornery3;
private double xtmax;
private double xtmin;
private double ytmax;
private double ytmin;
private Double[] corners;

public Triangle (double cornerx1, double cornery1, double cornerx2, double cornery2, double cornerx3, double cornery3){
    corners = new Double [6];
    corners[0] = cornerx1;
    corners[1] = cornery1;
    corners[2] = cornerx2;
    corners[3] = cornery2;
    corners[4] = cornerx3;
    corners[5] = cornery3;
}
public void maxAndMinTriangle (){ // find the minimum and maximum of the plane according to this triangle
    xtmax = corners[0];  
    for(int i=1;i < corners.length;i += 2){  
        if(corners[i] > xtmax){  
            xtmax = corners[i];
        }
    }

    xtmin = corners[0];  
    for(int i=1;i < corners.length;i += 2){  
        if(corners[i] < xtmin){  
            xtmin = corners[i];
        }
    }

    ytmax = corners[1];  
    for(int i=1;i < corners.length;i += 2){  
        if(corners[i] > ytmax){  
            ytmax = corners[i];
        }
    }

    ytmin = corners[1];  
    for(int i=1;i < corners.length;i += 2){  
        if(corners[i] < ytmin){  
            ytmin = corners[i];
        }
    }
}
public double getXTMax (){
    return xtmax;
}

public double getYTMax () {
    return ytmax;
}
public double getXTMin() {
    return xtmin;
}
public double getYTMin(){
    return ytmin;
}


//public static boolean isLeft (double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2, double x3, double y3){
    //return ( 0 <= ( ( x2 - x1 ) * ( y - y1) )- (( y2 - y1) * ( x - x1)));
//}

public boolean isLeft1 (double randX, double randY){ // find if this point is to the left of the first line
    return ( 0 <= ( ( corners[2] - corners[0] ) * ( randY - corners[1]) )- (( corners[3] - corners[1]) * ( randX - corners[0])));
}
public boolean isLeft2 (double randX, double randY){ // find if this point is to the left of the second line
    return ( 0 <= ( ( corners[4] - corners[0]) * ( randY - corners[1]) )- (( corners[5] - corners[1]) * ( randX - corners[0])));
}
public boolean isLeft3 (double randX, double randY){ // find if this point is to the left of the third line
    return ( 0 <= ( ( corners[4] - corners[2] ) * ( randY - corners[3]) )- (( corners[5] - corners[3]) * ( randX - corners[2])));
}

public boolean outsideTriangle ( double randX, double randY ){ // find if this point is inside of the triangle
    int counter = 0;
    if (isLeft1(randX,randY)){
        counter++;
    }
    if (isLeft2(randX,randY)){
        counter++;
    }
    if (isLeft3(randX,randY)){
        counter++;
    }
    return counter == 2; // must be to the left of exactly 2 of the lines
}}
```

And then the AreaEstimator class:

```
public class AreaEstimator{


public static double[] maxAndMinValues (Circle[] circles,Triangle[] triangles){
 // find maximum and minimum values according to all of the triangles and circles
    double xmax = -100;
    double ymax = -100;
    double xmin = 100;
    double ymin = 100;
    for (int l=0; l < circles.length; l++){
        if (xmax < circles[l].getXCMax()){
            xmax = circles[l].getXCMax();
        }
        if (ymax < circles[l].getYCMax()){
            ymax = circles[l].getYCMax();
        }
        if (xmin > circles[l].getXCMin()){
            xmin = circles[l].getXCMin();
        }
        if (ymin > circles[l].getYCMin()){
            ymin = circles[l].getYCMin();
        }
    }
    for ( int m = 0; m < triangles.length; m++){
        if(xmax < triangles[m].getXTMax()){
            xmax = triangles[m].getXTMax();
        }
        if(ymax < triangles[m].getYTMax()){
            ymax = triangles[m].getYTMax();
        }
        if(xmin > triangles[m].getXTMin()){
            xmin = triangles[m].getXTMin();
        }
        if(ymin > triangles[m].getYTMin()){
            ymin = triangles[m].getYTMin();
        }
    }
    double[] result = new double [4];
    result[0] = xmax;
    result[1] = ymax;
    result[2] = xmin;
    result[3] = ymin;
    return result;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    double numThrows = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); // initialize amount of throws
    if (numThrows <= 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    int countCircles = 0; // find the amount of circles given
    for ( int i = 1; i<args.length; i++){
        if(args[i].equals("circle")){
            countCircles++;             
        }
    }

    Circle[] circles = new Circle [countCircles];

    for ( int i = 1; i<args.length; i++){
        if (args[i].equals("circle")){
            for ( int k = 0; k< countCircles; k++){
                double xcenter = Double.parseDouble(args[i+1]);
                double ycenter = Double.parseDouble(args[i+2]);
                double radius = Double.parseDouble(args[i+3]);
                circles[k] = new Circle (xcenter, ycenter, radius); //values associated with this circle
                circles[k].maxAndMinCircle();//max and min value of the circle itself
            }
        }
    }

    int countTriangles = 0; // find the amount of the triangles given
    for ( int i = 1; i < args.length; i++){
        if(args[i].equals("triangle")){
            countTriangles++;
        }
    }

    Triangle[] triangles = new Triangle [countTriangles];

    for ( int i = 1; i<args.length; i++){
        if (args[i].equals("triangle")){
            for ( int p = 0; p< countTriangles; p++){
                double cornerx1 = Double.parseDouble(args[i+1]);
                double cornery1 = Double.parseDouble(args[i+2]);
                double cornerx2 = Double.parseDouble(args[i+3]);
                double cornery2 = Double.parseDouble(args[i+4]);
                double cornerx3 = Double.parseDouble(args[i+5]);
                double cornery3 = Double.parseDouble(args[i+6]);

                triangles[p] = new Triangle (cornerx1, cornery1, cornerx2, cornery2, cornerx3, cornery3);
                //values associated with this triangle
                triangles[p].maxAndMinTriangle(); //max and min value of the triangle itself
            }
        }
    }


    boolean dartsInOverlap = true;
    double countInOverlap = 0; // initialize amount of darts in the overlapping shape   
    double[]result = maxAndMinValues(circles,triangles);

    for(int i= 0;i < numThrows;i++){
        double randX= (Math.random() * (result[0]-result[2]) + result[2]) ; // generate a random x value
        double randY= (Math.random() * (result[1]-result[3])+ result[3]); // generate a random y value



        for ( int h = 0; h < circles.length && dartsInOverlap; h++){
            if (circles[h].outsideCircle(randX, randY)){
                dartsInOverlap = false; // if the point is outside of the circle, it returns false
            }
        }
        for ( int q = 0; q < triangles.length && dartsInOverlap; q++){
            if (triangles[q].outsideTriangle(randX, randY)){
                dartsInOverlap = false; // if the point is outside of the triangle, it returns false
            }
        }
        if (dartsInOverlap){
            countInOverlap++; // counts up the amount of points in the overlapping shape
        }
        dartsInOverlap = true;
    }
    System.out.println("This many darts were in the overlap between the shapes:" + countInOverlap); 
    // counts up the amount of points in the overlapping shape
    System.out.println("The estimated overlapped areas is" + (result[0]-result[2])*(result[1]-result[3]) *(countInOverlap/numThrows));
    //finds estimated area
}}
```

My code has worked for a few test cases, if in the command line there is only a circle and triangle entered, or only a sole circle. A triangle by itself or any other combination will give me answers far from the desired area estimation. I have looked and reviewed my code, and it all seems logical. So, where in my code could the problem persist? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is at least a typo in maxAndMinTriangle. You wrote a **1** where you need a **0**

```
xtmax = corners[0];  
for(int i=1;i < corners.length;i += 2){  
...
xtmin = corners[0];  
for(int i=1;i < corners.length;i += 2){
```

it should be

```
xtmax = corners[0];  
for(int i=0;i < corners.length;i += 2){  
...
xtmin = corners[0];  
for(int i=0;i < corners.length;i += 2){
```